# JSON parse data in javascript from php

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve data in a javascript file from a php file using json.

```
$items = array(); 
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $rows = array( 
        "id_locale" => $r['id_locale'], 
        "latitudine" => $r['lat'], 
        "longitudine" => $r['lng'] 
    ); 
    array_push($items, array("item" => $rows)); 
} 
ECHO json_encode($items);
```

and in the javascript file I try to recover the data using an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"Locali.php",
    success:function(data){
        alert("1");
        //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(idata);
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        alert("2");
        for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
            point = new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].item.latitudine,json[i].item.longitudine);
            alert(point);
        }
    }
})
```

The first alert is printed, the latter does not, it gives me error: Unexpected token <.... but I do not understand what it is.

Anyone have any idea where am I wrong?

I also tried to recover the data with jquery but with no positive results.

Comment: Don't use `JSON.parse` in your `success` function. Give your `$.ajax` attribute `dataType: 'json'` and then `console.log` the JSON response to see whether you got a null or an object with properties. If you got a null, something's wrong with the data in your PHP script.

Comment: Also try putting `exit();` after `json_encode()` function

Comment: my JSON data is: [{"item":{"id_locale":"50","latitudine":"44.4794995","longitudine":"11.364192099999968"}}] in JSON lint the json file is ok

Comment: adding exit(), dont' work, now I try with the console.log

Comment: If You specify `dataType: 'json'` in Your jQuery AJAX call it should be enough in Your PHP script to do `return $items;` instead of `echo json_encode($items);`.

Comment: N.B. I try with this: $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"Locali.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            var json = JSON.parse(data); but in the log there is nothing

Comment: adding dataType: 'json' and change json_encode($items); in return $items my page don't load, all blank     You can watch my problem here: http://www.livebo.it/temp/Locali.php

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$.post("Locali.php",{
    // any parameters you want to pass
},function(d){
    alert("1");
    for (var i=0; i<d.length; i++) {
      point = new google.maps.LatLng(d[i].item.latitudine,d[i].item.longitudine);
      alert(point);
    }
}, 'json');
```

the PHP is fine if it is giving the response you mentioned above.

Comment: how can I take the parameters?

Comment: you were not passing any parameters in your question, but I left the area open because I almost always pass something.  they would be in array format.  simpler; where the comment is you could pass comma delineated data like `name:value, name2:value2`

Answer (score 0):

data    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType: json,
        url:"Locali.php",
        success:function(data){
            for (i in data) {
            point = new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].item.latitudine,json[i].item.longitudine);
            alert(point);
            }
        }
    })

Try it like that.

Comment: variable `json` is not defined (when making variable `point`), return variable in what you wrote is `data`

Answer (score 0):

You should be Ok with this slight modifications:

```php
$items = array(); 
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $items[] = array( 
        "id_locale" => $r['id_locale'], 
        "latitudine" => $r['lat'], 
        "longitudine" => $r['lng'] 
    ); 
} 
echo json_encode($items);
```

And the jQuery:

```js
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url:"Locali.php",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            point = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].item.latitudine,data[i].item.longitudine);
            alert(point);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Didn't... If You specify the `dataType:'json'` it is not required to `json_encode` the PHP response...This is how I use it in many projects...

Comment: I have never heard of that before.  maybe I will try it sometime.  I would think that the PHP response would just be `Array()`

Comment: The difference is I am using `return $items;` instead of echoing json string... So any array or object get passed directly to AJAX call as response...

Comment: so you are saying that PHP automatically encodes arrays into JSON format.  I did not know that.  It serializes the array no matter what type of characters are used?

Comment: @NappingRabbit I didn't say PHP automatically encodes something to JSON... How/Where did You come on me saying this? :-)

Comment: @Stefania That is probably because of nothing is echoed. Open FireBug in Firefox on Console tab and look whether there is something logged to the console...

Comment: @shadyyx because you are receiving a response as `datatype:JSON`  I couldn't see it working except by accident.

Comment: @shadyyx there is nothing in the console tab too!

Comment: the message is: There has been declared the character encoding of the HTML document. The document appears with the text incomprehensible in some settings in the browser if it contains characters outside the US-ASCII. The character encoding of a page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: @NappingRabbit Sorry for the mistyfication - I looked at out framework and the base controller class. It checks whether the request comes from AJAX (the call contains parameter `async=1`) and in that case it takes the response from the action called (in my case the `return`) and echoes it `json_encode`d... Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Stefania Sorry, my bad, in PHP You really have to have `echo json_encode($items);` at the end instead of `return`. Try it now...

Comment: now I can see the page, but i think that not working, because my log panel is empty, and the alert is not show. now I have:  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url:"Locali.php",
    success:function(data){
        alert("1");
        console.log(data);
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            point = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].item.latitudine,data[i].item.longitudine);
            alert(point);
        }
    }
}) and no alert show

Answer (score 0):

I think u should look more for the data you are getting from the php file. Definitely this is a parse error and must be missing some bracket/something else, ultimately not making the data returned to be a json parseable string.

Answer (score -1):

yeah just try

```
for (var i=0; i<json[0].length; i++) {
```

cause you have an object there..